# To find n using CLT

Tags: probability, statistics, central-limit-theorem

A distribution with unknown mean μ has a variance equal to 1.5. Use central limit theorem to find how large a sample should be taken from the distribution in order that the probability will atleast be 0.95 that the sample mean will be within 0.5 of the population mean.

My try:
$P(|\overline{X} -\mu| \leq 0.5) \ge 0.95$

$P\left(\frac{|\overline{X}  - μ|}{\frac{\sqrt{1.5}}{\sqrt{n}}} ≤ \frac{0.5}{\frac{\sqrt{1.5}}{\sqrt{n}}}\right) \ge 0.95$

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there...

$$\mathbb{P}\left[\frac{|\overline{X}_n-\mu|}{\sqrt{1.5}}\sqrt{n}\le \frac{0.5}{\sqrt{1.5}}\sqrt{n}  \right]\ge 0.95$$

$$\mathbb{P}\left[|Z|\le \frac{0.5}{\sqrt{1.5}}\sqrt{n}  \right]\ge 0.95$$

that is

$$\frac{0.5}{\sqrt{1.5}}\sqrt{n} \geq 1.96$$

or

$$n\ge 23.05=24$$

---

as already noted in the comments by @Misha Lavrov, *ceteris paribus*, $n=24$ is not great enough to grant a good approximation of the result so, in absence of other satisfied conditions, other ways have to be taken into consideration, for example, Cebishev's inequality, by which

$$\mathbb{P}\left\{ |\overline{X}_n-\mu|<0.5  \right\}\geq 1-\frac{1.5}{0.5^2 n}$$

thus

$$n\geq 120$$

---

As 120 is very large w.r.t. 24, another way would be to analyze the $n\ge 24$ length' sample with some non-parametric tests to prove its normality

Comment: Of course, this calculation is actually bullshit; the CLT promises that as $n \to \infty$, the normal approximation will be good, but makes absolutely no guarantees that it will be good when $n=24$. But it's the bullshit calculation that a nonrigorous statistics class will expect.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: of course I 100% agree with you!

Comment: @ Misha Lavrov; Can you please take a look at this question if you have time? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4506330/different-types-of-markov-chains ? thank you so much!